# Native Android Application crashes at startup with "Cannot load library: reloc_library[1315] ..."

Tags: android-ndk

I have several static libraries which aggregates into one dynamic library (.so) in main Android.mk file... So, everything compiles without warnings, but when I try to start my application I get this error:

```
Cannot load library: reloc_library[1315]:   226 cannot locate '_ZNSt12__node_alloc13_M_deallocateEPvj'...\n
```

It looks like the function is from the stl, but my application.mk include

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

any idea?

Comment: the table of symbols of my .so file:

30: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT ***UND*** _ZNSt12__node_alloc13_M_deallocateEPvj

Comment: It was resolved by itself... I don't know why but it became linkable after  asome random chnges in project settings...